# how do i solve this error cannot set MyLocation of null in ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

hello how can i solve this error, i am using google maps in ionic and getting direction from current location to a particular location, but i got this error and how do i solve it,
here is my typescript file

```
declared:this
MyLocation: any;

calculateAndDisplayRoute(){
  //let this = that;
  let that = this;
  let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  //geolocation

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(pos);
      //set current locatin
      this.MyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(pos);
      console.log('sample here');

    }, function () {

    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  }
  //end of geolocation
  directionsService.route({
    origin: this.MyLocation,
    destination: this.Destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. This might work.
The only difference made

```
let self = this
```

and set **MyLocation** with **self.MyLocation**.

```
declared:this
MyLocation: any;

calculateAndDisplayRoute(){

  let that = this;
  let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  let self = this;
  //geolocation

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(pos);
      //set current locatin
      self.MyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(pos);
      console.log('pos');

    }, function () {

    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  }
  //end of geolocation
  directionsService.route({
    origin: this.MyLocation,
    destination: this.Destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```